# Is it possible to use Azure Mobile Services with WP7

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone

I realize there will be additional work (as the SDK only works on Windows 8 and WP8) as the SDK provides controls to provide a login sequence (via Microsoft Account, Facebook, etc).

I am wondering if it is possible to achieve the same result with a Windows Phone 7 app? I've been searching for a while, and there is not much on Mobile Services at all, let alone for WP7. Is there some (technical?) reason (besides the fact that WP7 is not the latest and greatest) that Microsoft has left WP7 out in the cold with Azure Services?

I realize that just accessing the data via REST in WP7 is trivial, but I'm really getting at is the entire process  of using deferred authentication restricting access to users own data only, is this doable without their SDK without a monumental effort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A preview of the new C# client which supports Windows Phone 7.5 is now [available](http://nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.MobileServices/) to try out. Remember it is pre-release and therefore not supported. http://www.johanlaanstra.nl/?p=217

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the SDK is open source, and the source is at https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-mobile-services .

Now, I haven't dug into the source, and don't know what the porting effort might look like, but it seems reasonable to think that it shouldn't be too much of an effort.

Good luck, and share it back if you make progress.  :)

Adam Hoffman

Windows Azure Blog - http://stratospher.es

Twittererer - @stratospher_es

Answer (score 1):

Officially no I am afraid.
But you can find a (partial) client platform agnostic implementation in a form of a C# SDK here:
https://github.com/kenegozi/azure-mobile-csharp-sdk
This will allow you to use Azure Mobile Services with WP7 I guess.